# Raspberry Pi 2 crashes on manual ifconfig command

Tags: crash

I'm trying to manually set IP configuration on my raspberry pi 2. Using SSH I run the following command in the terminal

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

my raspberry pi then does a full system crash and I have to shut it off and turn it back on in order for it to be responsive again.

I expect the Raspberry Pi to accept the manually given address that I am giving it, but instead I get a crash. For the record my Raspberry Pi boots up and says the version is 4.14.79-v7+

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please explain your configuration in more detail. From what device do you ssh into your pi? Via what interface? Are you sure your Pi crashes and not only cuts off your ssh connection?

Comment: Do you connect to the RasPi by WiFi with SSH?

Comment: The Pi is being connected via ethernet to the computer.. I SSH into my pi via my computer using PUTTY. It is possible it only cuts off my connection, but I am unable to reestablish a new ssh connection until the PI is restarted

Comment: Well that's your explanation. Your SSH session stops as soon as the IP address of the interface you connected to changes.

Comment: what's the IP of the computer? is it also 10.0.0.x/255.255.255.0 (where x is 1-254 but not 100) ? if any of that is not true, then of course you can't connect to the pi until it gets the IP you can connect to when it boots